# GcmBroadcastReceiver cannot resolve problems (Android studio)

Tags: android

I have problems in my manifest file that says that cannot identify the `android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"` and the `<service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />`, I definitely can't find a solution, I really need help in this, I already install all google play services, also the gradle I updated with the next dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0',  
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.0.0"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pedrobal.chatonline" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.pedrobal.chatonline.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.appsrox.instachat.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver" 
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.pedrobal.chatonline" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" /> 
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create `GcmBroadcastReceiver` receiver under `com.example.pedrobal.chatonline` package in your project